# Как запустить сервер на поддомене (nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

Например, если запустить статический сервер так:

```
var http = require('http');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('dir1');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(80);

console.log('Server running on port 80');
```

то, когда человек заходит на `mysite.ru` ему будут передаваться данные из папки `dir1`.

Как написать подобный код, но чтобы файлы выдавались при вводе поддомена `subdomain.mysite.ru`?

Comment: а dns правильно настроен и знает о этом домене?

Comment: @KoVadim, да знает.

Comment: если оба домена ссылаются на один адрес, то нужно делать проверку ручками - как то так:

`http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var host = req.get('host');
  if (host === 'subdomain.mysite.ru')
    file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(80);`

Comment: @KoVadim, Не работает: `TypeError: req.get is not a function`.

Comment: А вот так: `req.headers.host` работает.

Comment: и `req.host` должен работать

Comment: @KoVadim, так тоже пробовал. У меня последняя версия ноды. Возможно из-за этого. Решение оказалось простым.

Comment: есть ещё красивое решение - поставить перед нодой apache или nginx и настроить проксирование.